# How to maintain white background when using opencv warpaffine

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rotation, image-rotation

I'm trying to rotate image using

```
void rotate(cv::Mat& src, double angle, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    int len = std::max(src.cols, src.rows);
    cv::Point2f pt(len / 2., len / 2.);
    cv::Mat r = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(pt, angle, 1.0);
    cv::warpAffine(src, dst, r, cv::Size(src.cols, src.rows));
}
```

by giving angle, source and destination image. Rotation works correctly as follows.

[image]

I want to make black areas white. I have tried with

```
cv::Mat dst = cv::Mat::ones(src.cols, src.rows, src.type());
```

before calling rotate, but no change in result. How can I achieve this?

Note: I am looking for solution which achieve this while doing the rotation. obviously by making black areas white after the rotation this can be achieved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will want to use the `borderMode` and `borderValue` arguments of the `warpAffine` function to accomlish this. By setting the mode to `BORDER_CONSTANT` it will use a constant value for border pixels (i.e. outside the image), and you can set the value to the constant value you want to use (i.e. white). It would look something like:

```
cv::warpAffine(src, dst, r,
               cv::Size(src.cols, src.rows),
               cv::INTER_LINEAR,
               cv::BORDER_CONSTANT,
               cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));
```

For more details see the [OpenCV API Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#warpaffine).

Comment: what to do if you would like to discard all those pixels out of bounds, like including only those pixels inside of valid roi. Is there any method for that?

Comment: @PabloGonzalez There is no method in the API for that, you'll have to write your own method to take those pixels out of whatever you're doing.